# Error while Installing tensorflow on aarch64

Tags: python, tensorflow, h5py, arm64

I am new to Tensorflow and Python. I am trying to install the tenserflow on the aarch64 platform. I am getting the multiple errors while installing.

```
pip -V
pip 20.2.4
python3 -V
Python 3.7.8
```

Trying to install

```
pip install tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_aarch64.whl
```

1. scipy issue - hang at this package (wait for >30 minute)

```
pip install scipy==1.4.1
Collecting scipy==1.4.1
  Using cached scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz (24.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... -
```

Resolved above error, rename the whl file to 'scipy-1.4.1-cp37-**none-any**.whl'

Now,
2. Error H5py and grpcio package

```
Building wheel for h5py (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tc9d3e6a/h5py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tc9d3e6a/h5py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-77z7aeys
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tc9d3e6a/h5py/
  Complete output (64 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/highlevel.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_threads.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_deprecation.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  running build_ext
  Loading library to get version: libhdf5.so
  error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
  Running setup.py clean for h5py
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl size=73673 sha256=519c1644261286c7765d6a1670caddd6eaada06528c01ed7220c9097dec827c1
  Stored in directory: /home/root/.cache/pip/wheels/62/76/4c/aa25851149f3f6d9785f6c869387ad82b3fd37582fa8147ac6
  Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... -
```

Error Resolved by downloading the whl file of grcpio from,
https://www.piwheels.org/project/grpcio/#install

Next error, H5py package issue.  (**Hang here :(** )

```
pip install tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_aarch64.whl
Processing ./tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_aarch64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.4.1)
Processing ./.cache/pip/wheels/62/76/4c/aa25851149f3f6d9785f6c869387ad82b3fd37582fa8147ac6/wrapt-1.12.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.3.3 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.33.2)
Collecting h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0.tar.gz (301 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.1.2)
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (459 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.35.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.9.2->tensorflow==2.3.0) (50.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5" in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5"->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (0.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow==2.3.0) (3.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-heaudpgr
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/
  Complete output (64 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/highlevel.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_threads.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_deprecation.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
  running build_ext
  Loading library to get version: libhdf5.so
  error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
  Running setup.py clean for h5py
Failed to build h5py
Installing collected packages: wrapt, h5py, opt-einsum, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow
  Attempting uninstall: h5py
    Found existing installation: h5py 2.9.0
    Uninstalling h5py-2.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled h5py-2.9.0
    Running setup.py install for h5py ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-nl0kilnr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.7m/h5py
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/
    Complete output (64 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
    copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
    copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
    copying h5py/highlevel.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
    copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
    copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/_hl
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_threads.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_deprecation.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
    copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
    copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
    copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
    copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/h5py/tests/test_vds
    running build_ext
    Loading library to get version: libhdf5.so
    error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of h5py
  Moving to /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py
   from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~5py
  Moving to /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.9.0-py3.7.egg-info
   from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~5py-2.9.0-py3.7.egg-info
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-glz1u_0g/h5py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-nl0kilnr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.7m/h5py Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It needs the native HDF5 library, did you install it?

Comment: Hey, I'm also getting the next error H5PY

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, Yes Looks like dependent. Modified the my case. I'm facing the h5py error. Searching the aarch64 whl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the aarch64 related packages are getting resolved from
https://www.piwheels.org/project/grpcio/#install.

Note:- Just rename the file to <python_package_name>----<linux_aarch64>.whl from  or .

Comment: You mean to call a server using grpcio package as a client?

Answer (score -1):

Not relevent but I'd recommend using archiconda.
[Archiconda Build Tools](https://github.com/Archiconda/build-tools/releases)

Comment: Thanks, but Its not relavant to my case

Comment: Yes i mentioned that.

Comment: By the way did you try installing tensorflow nightly build?